# GNU 'Screen' clears some or all of the output history displayed in the terminal when attach to the screen

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, gnu-screen

I use [autossh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/autossh) and also [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) on my Ubuntu server, because of the poor internet connection I have, I use both to keep my connection alive even when my internet connection is lost... But I experienced a lot of problems when I first used screen as my terminal in ssh, such as scrolling problems (I use kali linux nethunter on a mobile phone when connecting to my server) but that seems to have been resolved and I can scroll now. I'm used to using basic SSH to connect to my Ubuntu server, and I'm comfortable when using it. When I connect using SSH like this:

Screenshot: [Login to the Ubuntu server using SSH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ma0pEl.jpg)

Look at the output history above that, SSH doesn't clear it when I connected to the server... But when I use `autossh + screen` with this command:

> AUTOSSH_GATETIME=5 autossh -M 0 -- -o "ServerAliveInterval 0" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 1" -R 2202:localhost:22 -L 8080:localhost:80  -t root@192.168.100.1 -p 8288 $'bash -c 'exec screen -RD''

Screenshot: [Run autossh and screen commands simultaneously](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMVrol.jpg)

When successfully connected to the server, the screen deletes the existing output history, and the command prompt moves to the top of the terminal like this:

Screenshot: [All history is cleared by the screen, and the command prompt moves to the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdrPvl.jpg)

I don't want this to happen when using `autossh + screen`, I want it to **run like normal ssh**, I mean, I don't want **screen to cover the terminal**, and do not want the **command prompt to move around**, and just **be like basic ssh**.

Does someone have a solution for this? I would be very grateful if someone would help me, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

That's not going to work with `screen`.

Screen *is* indeed a whole terminal running inside your regular terminal, interpreting control sequences and outputting new ones; it's designed this way so that it could fully restore the environment you're working in – not just when your connection is interrupted and you're reattaching from the exact same terminal, but also when one is attaching from somewhere else entirely, where one would *want* Screen to bring the scrollback – or when one uses Ctrl-A to switch between multiple 'windows' in the same Screen session, each of which has its own scrollback.

This is in part because terminal apps have no reliable way to update your terminal scrollback history (and also in Screen's early days they were physical terminals that didn't have such a thing at all), so the only decent option for Screen is to disable that (using the "altscreen" output mode) and to handle scrolling all on its own.

(The other reason is that Screen allows you to *split* the screen into multiple vertical or horizontal panes, each having its own scrollback history, and that's just entirely incompatible with relying on the parent terminal's scrolling.)

`tmux` also works the same way but is in many regards a better alternative to Screen. (Except for its default Ctrl-B choice of hotkey, which I always change back to Ctrl-A.) I'd suggest trying it first; chances are you'll quickly get used to working in this environment. (Many people use screen/tmux through the `byobu` wrapper. `zellij` is another extra-fancy terminal multiplexer.)

You could try **`dtach`**, which does not do full terminal emulation – it only attaches and detaches the output, just like you want – but the consequences are that it doesn't support switching between multiple windows like screen/tmux do, or properly restoring state of full-screen apps.

**`abduco`** might be a more modern alternative to dtach. (It's meant to be used together with dvtm which is also a full-screen multiplexer, so I'm not sure how well it handles non-altscreen apps – never tried it myself.)

Finally, I would recommend a completely different approach which is to set up a **WireGuard VPN tunnel** to one of your servers that has a stable connection (commercial WireGuard-based VPN services should also do the job), then use regular SSH through that. Most kinds of VPN tunnels will already prevent the connection from dying when your IP address changes (or being killed by the router when its NAT states are reset), but WireGuard in particular is quite good at handling lossy and unreliable connections as well as client IP changes. On top of that, it works well in a multipoint configuration where you'd connect to each server directly, as well as a central gateway configuration.

Tailscale and Innernet are two WireGuard-based VPN tools if you don't feel like setting up the tunnel from scratch. Some other VPN products such as ZeroTier also have similar useful properties (OpenVPN less so, although it can be made to work if you twiddle with the auto-reconnect settings).